# Specifying external libraries but not at function level

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a question about specifying external libraries using roxygen2. To import other packages I just have to add within function description `@import <package_name>`. But is there any way how can we do it not at function level I mean not as function description? Bringing external packages at function level in my opinion can bring problems in future when modifying functions within package. For example if I do not want to have function in my package, it's very easy to delete it with imports within it.

**To summarize**

Is there any possibility how can I refer to external package but not at function level, but more at package level when building package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dedicated `myPackage.R` file with general package description as well as global imports, see [Documenting Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-packages) :

```
#' Package Title
#' 
#' Description of my package
#' 
#' Link to the functions of MyPackage :
#' * [function1()]
#' * [function2()]
#' * [...]
#' 
#' 
#' @author Me, Others
#' @docType package
#' @name myPackage
#' @import otherPackage 
NULL
```

The `NULL` at the end is needed, as this file doesn't refer to a specific object in the package.